# How do I get my ng-bootstrap carousel images to slide?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng-bootstrap

I would like to have my carousel images either fade in and out or slide to the left as the original bootstrap does by default. I cannot figure it out

Answer (score 0):

make sure you include the bootstrap js as well as the css.

Comment: I did. This does not work either because it is using a ng bootstrap carousel

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post your code as is so we can get a better idea of your problem.

Have you installed all necessary dependencies and are you using the right syntax?
There really isn't much we can do to help you without knowing your setup.

Have you already gotten the basic `<ngb-carousel>` element to display correctly?